# Does Next.js generates one page per every post in the following configuration?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm rendering dynamically a list of posts using next/router. This list contains the index, path, and title of every post is:

```
export const items = [

    {
      id: "0",
      path: 'Post_Alpha',
      title: "Title example 0",
    },

    {
      id: "1",
      path: 'Post_Beta',
      title: "Title example 1",

    },
```

I can access to the post beta by its index in the array:

```
    import {items} from '../posts/data'

function Posts() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const {post} = router.query 
    const postIndex = items.map(function(e) { return e.path; }).indexOf(post)
    const post = items[courseIndex]

    return (
    <h2>
        {post.title}
    </h2>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

I wonder whether Next.js creates a page for every post or it only creates one that is dynamically populated. I have a list of links that use `<Link /> from 'next/link'` to go to every post. In addition, how can I see the pages that Next.js is generating, like the sitemap.xml of a site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I do not think it does.**

I think that only happens when you use the `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`. In your case, your pages do not have the features of using *Next.js* as a service, such as good SEO. You just use *client-side* fetching, which does not take advantage of any of the benefits of Next.js. You could check also the [useSWR()](https://swr.vercel.app/) hook for fetching data on the client.

## Edit

I believe you should follow [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#reading-files-use-processcwd) example from *Next.js* Documentation if your data are not so many and are not updated frequently. Only use, if you qualify both of the above requirements, as the data are static and will be generated at build time.

Comment: Would it work using [process.cwd()](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) instead of userSWR()?

Comment: `process.cwd()` is not for caching and SEO, it is for you to access files in the directory when you **build** the project, where *Next.js* generates a new directory and adds new files. I hope I answered your comment

Comment: So I should fetch the data like this:   `const { data, error } = useSWR("path/to/client data file", fetcher)`, right? In addition, should I fetch .js file or .json?